# Problems of Rotational Body at Uniform Speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, centripetal-force

> [image: 1]
>
> In this figure, $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass is connected to a $2 \;\text{kg}$ mass through a inflexible string. The $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass is on the surface of a table and through a hole on the table the string went down and $2 \;\text{kg}$ mass is hanging from that string. $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass is now rotating at a uniform speed and it's coefficient of sliding friction $\mu_k=0.2$

### ***Questions:***

---

1. > Write down Newton's Equation for the $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass moving at a
   > uniform speed.

**My Attempt:** I think they are asking for Equations of Angular Motion (What else could be?). But if something is moving at uniform speed, does it mean it has uniform angular velocity? If so, then the only equation I can think about is $\theta= \theta_0 + \omega t$ where $\theta_0$ and $\theta$ are the initial and final position of the $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass respectively. Is my assumption correct? How can I improve it?

2. > What is the work done due to the rotation of the uniform speed of $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass?

**My Attempt:** Now I am a bit confused here. In the original context, they mention about coefficient of sliding friction. That means there is friction present in our consideration. If I only consider work done due to centripetal force, it would be $0$ because of $90°$ angle. But if friction is present, should we consider extra torque is applied to the $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass to keep it's speed uniform?

3. > If we want to keep $2 \;\text{kg}$ mass stationary on its place (which is hanging) then what
   > should be the speed of $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass?

**My Attempt:** Here, I considered for $2 \;\text{kg}$ mass the resultant motion is zero, which means it's acceleration $(a)$ would be zero. So, if we consider the Tension force from the $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass to keep $2 \;\text{kg}$ mass from falling is L, then $2 \times 9.8-L=ma=2 \times 0 \implies L=19.6 \;\text{N}$. But where does the tension force from $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ comes from? I thought it's from the centrifugal (or centripetal) force. But should I take into account friction now? If the friction if $f_k$ then can I write this $\frac{mv^2}{r}-f_k-L=0$ in the next step to find out speed of the $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass?

4. > If the speed of $1.5 \;\text{kg}$ mass decrease due to friction, then draw the effective Velocity vs. Time graph of the $2 \;\text{kg}$ mass.

**My Attempt:** Like the 3rd question, I would consider $$2 \times 9.8-L=ma=2 \cdot a$$  for the $2 \;\text{kg}$ mass but here $a$ isn't $0$. Now how can I attempt to draw it?

Please help me solving my question. I am struggling with it for hours. Even if you can answer 1 or 2 question please do it. I desperately need your help.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: There's another interesting question (question 5) that I highly recommend you try after you solved the first 4 questions, which is to find the frequency of small oscillations of the system about the equilibrium point (assume that the table is frictionless), in the direction of the string. That is, the $2 \;\text{kg}$ mass is oscillating in the pure vertical direction (up and down).

Comment: @VincentThacker, so no one is answering me. I see someone down voted too. I am not a native english speaker. I tried to translate it to my best.

Comment: As I have explained above, asking for homework help is off-topic here. We do not answer such questions.

Comment: Repost of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652252/finding-out-rotational-speed-of-a-mass with a different account.  Please don't multiply post your questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Newton's equation would have two components. To maintain the centripetal acceleration you need a tension in the string T = m$v^2$/R.  To counter the friction and maintain a constant speed, you need an external tangential force F = $μ_k$mg.
2. The external force supplies power = Fv.
3. Set T = (2 kg)g to support the weight of the lower mass.
4. Without the external force, the torque from friction would cause a decrease in the angular momentum, a decrease in the tension, a decrease in the radius, and allow the lower mass to accelerate downward. Starting from equilibrium, its downward velocity would start at zero and increase with time (in a complex fashion and ending at zero when the upper mass hits the hole).
I set up a numeric simulation of this system using a fixed xy system with its origin at the hole. I let t = 0 when the external force was removed and Δt = 0.01 sec. The upper mass started at x = 0.5 m and y = 0 with an equilibrium $v_y$ of 2.556 m/s. It followed a spiral path in toward the origin completing one cycle at t = 1.09 sec., and crossing the x axis at 0.3 m with a speed of  1.95 m/s.  The downward speed of the hanging mass increased slowly, reaching a maximum of 0.34 m/s just before the first half cycle and then decreased even more slowly after that.

Comment: Thanks, man. You saved me. By the way what are the components of Newton's Equation? And what is exactly meant by Newton's Equation in my question?

Comment: What is the relationship between Angular Momentum and Tension?

Comment: Newton's equation involves forces (in this case radial and tangential), yous was a kinematics equation.  In this case angular momentum is mvR, and tension is m$v^2$ /R.  I don't have the time to work out the details on question (4) and in any case, the monitors apparently felt that my original answer was too complete.

Comment: Why would I take into consideration equations of force where the speed is constant?

Comment: How does friction affect angular momentum? When coefficient of sliding friction $μ_k=0.2$